# Get total hours that fall between a specific time period

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

the condition is Time in and Time out (e.g 02/01/2015 02:55 'til 02/02/2015 05:55) that is more than a day. I already computed the total hours of Time in and Time out, and I want to know if the total hours has passed between 23:00(11:00PM ) up to 06:00AM and get the total of it

Comment: You could have tried something.

Comment: Hint: decompose that period of time into "a partial day starting at 10:11:03 and ending at midnight", "complete days" and "a partial day starting at midnight and ending at 02:19:38". The rest is fairly straightforward.

Comment: I don't have any idea yet on how to get those sir, what I did is, I listed all the TIMES passed by the timeIn up to the timeOut.

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "get the night times".

Comment: get the total night times, considering that night times will start at 23:00(11:00PM) and ends 06:00AM

Comment: I really wanted to post my output, however, i can't "account matter" .

Comment: With the property [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) you get midnight of any given `DateTime` value. In combination with [AddDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) you can easily get "midnight of the next day"; ex: `var midnightNextDay = value.AddDays(1).Date;`. To get the difference (in days) you can use [TotalDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx); ex: `(value2 - value1).TotalDays`. -- and there is also a [TotalHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx)...

Answer (score 2):

```
var hours = (datevalue1 - datevalue2).TotalHours;
```

or

```
Timespace ts= (datevalue1 - datevalue2);
var hours = ts.Value.TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.. `DateTime.Parse().Subtract()`

eg:

```
string startTime = "11:00 PM";
string endTime = "6:00 AM";

TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime));

Console.WriteLine(duration);
Console.ReadKey();
```

OR

`TimeSpan` is the object you need:

```
TimeSpan span = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now);

String.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", 
    span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate it by passing over time. when its night time add it to `TimeSpan`.

```
DateTime timeIn = new DateTime(2015, 09, 29, 10, 11, 3); // 29-09-2015 at 10:11:03
DateTime timeOut = new DateTime(2015, 10, 1, 2, 19, 18); // 01-10-2015 at 02:19:38
TimeSpan nightTime = new TimeSpan(); //total amount of night time
TimeSpan passLength = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1); // length of time to pass at each iteration (1s)

while (timeIn < timeOut) // do it until timeIn reaches timeOut
{
    timeIn = timeIn.Add(passLength); // add 1 second to timeIn
    if (timeIn.Hour < 6 || timeIn.Hour == 23) // if we are in range of night time
    {
        nightTime = nightTime.Add(passLength); // add 1 second to night time
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(nightTime);
```

You can do lot of optimizations. for long times its not good idea to add 1 sec each time. you can add 1 day to TimeIn at each iterate then add only 6 hours to night time. after you get close to Timeout decrease length time

Here is a better way. first get days fast. then get rest of the time.

```
DateTime timeIn = new DateTime(2015, 09, 29, 10, 11, 3); // 29-09-2015 at 10:11:03
DateTime timeOut = new DateTime(2015, 10, 1, 2, 19, 18); // 01-10-2015 at 02:19:38

// Get days
TimeSpan passLength = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0); // one day per iterate
while (timeIn + passLength < timeOut)
{
    timeIn = timeIn.Add(passLength);
    nightTime = nightTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 7, 0, 0)); // 7 hours of a day passed is considered night time
}

// Get rest of the time
passLength = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1); // one second per iterate
while (timeIn < timeOut) // do it until timeIn reaches timeOut
{
     timeIn = timeIn.Add(passLength); // add 1 second to timeIn
     if (timeIn.Hour < 6 || timeIn.Hour == 23) // if we are in range of night time
     {
         nightTime = nightTime.Add(passLength); // add 1 second to night time
     }
}

Console.WriteLine(nightTime);
```

You shouldn't be worry about rest of the time calculation performance. since the rest of the time is now less than 1 day which is only `86400` seconds.

Less than `86400` iterates should be fine for today's processors speed. how ever you can still optimize it farther away but you don't get much more performance.

Comment: You forgot about 11:00PM

Comment: I COMMEND YOU SIR FOR THIS, and also to those who've tried. THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit different and faster approach:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TimeSpan result = new TimeSpan();
        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2015, 09, 29, 10, 11, 03);
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2015, 10, 01, 02, 19, 38);
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(dt1.Year, dt1.Month, dt1.Day, 0, 0, 0); //Date only
        DateTime d2 = new DateTime(dt2.Year, dt2.Month, dt2.Day, 0, 0, 0); //Date only

        //Count night time in first day
        result += DateTime.Compare(dt1, d1.AddHours(6)) > 0 ? new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0) : new TimeSpan(dt1.Hour, dt1.Minute, dt1.Second);
        if (DateTime.Compare(dt1, d1.AddHours(23)) > 0) result += new TimeSpan(dt1.Hour - 23, dt1.Minute, dt1.Second);

        //Count night time in last day
        result += DateTime.Compare(dt2, d2.AddHours(6)) > 0 ? new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0) : new TimeSpan(dt2.Hour, dt2.Minute, dt2.Second);
        if (DateTime.Compare(dt2, d2.AddHours(23)) > 0) result += new TimeSpan(dt1.Hour - 23, dt2.Minute, dt2.Second);

        //Count night time in middle days
        int daysBetween = (int)(d2 - d1).TotalDays - 1;
        result += new TimeSpan(daysBetween * 7, 0, 0);

        Console.WriteLine("Night time: " + result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare `EndTime` with your Range`(23:00-06:00)`

that is in your Case, check wether  `EndTime 05:55` < `06:00` and `EndTime 05:55` > `23:00`

Comment: may you please explain further sir rajan ? :)

Comment: for example, StartTime is 21:00 and EndTime is 07:00, that gives a total of  10 Hours all in all, and a nighDiff ( the time 23:00 - 6:00) of 7 . How will I going to have tat 7? Please reply ... senpai

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the `DateTime` values to get the `TimeSpan` in between. Then you can get the `TotalHours` in that

```
var hours = timeOut.Subtract(timeIn).TotalHours;
```

For example

```
timeIn = 29-09-2015 10:11:03;
timeOut = 01-10-2015 02:19:38;
hours = 52.14303137125;
```

Comment: am already into that sir, my exact problem/question is, I wanted to know if the; Time In and Time Out of the employee pass to the time 23:00(11:00Pm) - 06:00 AM. Lookin forward for your reply sir

Comment: @SuperPruuylan This will always work as long as your `timeIn` and `timeOut` are `DateTime` objects. If you look at my example, the two time values are in separate dates, still they work as expected. Can you please try this once? If it still does not work, show your sample and comment here, I'll try to fix your problem :)

Comment: your codes hows on how to get the span between two times sir, if I made myself right. I'll just have another question for you if you don't mind. Let's say, I have a timeIn of 29-09-2015 at 10:11:03 and a timeOut of 01-10-2015 at 02:19:38, how will I get all the NIGHT TIMES of those considering that NIGHT TIMES will start at 23:00(11:00PM) and ends 06:00AM, same question as above but much clearer... I guess. Looking forward for your reply sir :)